# Is it common practice to style my page in jQuery?

Tags: jquery, css, performance, styling

Most of the appearance of my site is defined in my stylesheets, but I've found it much easier to define the "responsive parts" in jQuery.
For example:

```
var currentWidth = window.width();
$('#element').css('left', 0.1*currentWidth);
$('#element').width(0.9*currentWidth);
```

etc.

It works alright, everything is always in place, what I'm concerned about, is performance. Is it going to slow things down significantly compared to defining everything in CSS and let my site be a bit less tidy? 
I'm pretty much a newbie at this, I can usually come up with a solution, but I'm always getting confused about what's good practice and what's tinkering.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have you tried using width:100% ?

Comment: What if the user resizes the browser window? Is setting the element sizes in jQuery still easier?

Comment: It's included in $( window ).resize function, so that's not an issue. Defining height was the main reason I use jQuery for styling anyway(AFAIK that's not possible in CSS).

Comment: I still don't see how two lines of CSS is "less tidy" than five lines of jQuery. (And yes, it is possible to define the height in CSS.)

Comment: By less tidy I meant the layout, not the code. Sometimes, probably due to the lack of my experience I just find it easier to hold the proper layout across all screen sizes by using a bit of jQuery in addition to CSS. As it seems based on your answers I should stop doing that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you style your site in jQuery the list of the problems may occur:

1- jQuery takes longer than CSS to load, because CSS is a browser built in library, but not jQuery

2- if the user turns of javascript, your styles are not gonna be read

NOTE: never use jQuery unless it's absolutely necessary! you can use % in CSS if you want to achieve what you explained in your code!

Comment: Thank you for your answer. As I've stated above, most of the time I do this when I have to define height of an element based on the height of the viewport. Is there a way in CSS to do that?

Comment: you can use media queries and viewport, read the information in this link (https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Media_queries) to get some ideas!

Comment: this one is another useful link with some good information: http://html5hacks.com/blog/2012/11/28/elegantly-resize-your-page-with-the-at-viewport-css-declaration/

Answer (score 1):

It's not common practice to style a site with jQuery. You shoulden't make a site responsive with jQuery. CSS is the way to go.